# Insert aspx page as partial view inside razor page

Tags: asp.net, razor

I am trying to load an aspx page inside my razor code (mypage.cshtml). I have the following code, which does not work:

```
@Html.Partial("~/Video/Upload.aspx")
```

The error it gives is: The partial view '~/Video/Upload.aspx' was not found or no view engine supports the searched locations. The following locations were searched:
~/Video/Upload.aspx

Comment: I don't think you can mix Razor and Webforms in a single view. It would probably work if you used the webforms view engine for your views instead of razor.

Comment: I got it to work using iframe, so I may just go with that, unless there is a way to do the html.parital like in my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move Upload.aspx to your Views/Shared folder to make it reachable, and your partial will work.

Comment: how to make it reachable ?